# Am I supposed to ground the inverter or the battery or both to the vehicle chassis?

Tags: ground, inverter, grounding, solar-energy

I am setting up a solar system in a vehicle. I have 400W solar panels, a 12V battery bank, and a 2000W inverter. I've looked at the manuals and read online to figure out the wiring diagram below, but I'm still not sure if I can ground the inverter and the battery separately (this would be convenient since they are 10 feet away from each other) or if I need to connect them to each other and ground just one device.

Which am I supposed to ground, the battery or the inverter?

Feel free to point out any other problems with my diagram, I'm just here so I don't set myself on fire.

[image]

Comment: What is the make and model of inverter? Can you link to the installation instructions? Also, I notice that you show a 40A fuse in series with the inverter on the DC side. However, if the inverter is putting out 2000 W, the input current will probably be over 200 A at 12V. I would like to read the inverter installation instructions, but probably you need to ground the battery to chassis near the battery (DC ground) and ground the inverter to the chassis near the inverter (AC protective earth ground). But if you have a shore power input on the inverter, AC ground is more complicated.

Comment: @mkeith Here is the inverter: Aims 2000 Watt 12V Pure Sine Wave Inverter http://invertersrus.com/product/aims-pwrig200012120s/ and here is the installation instructions http://invertersrus.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Aims-PWRIG200012120S-Owners-Manual.pdf It says to connect the inverter directly to the battery and doesn't show any grounds.

There is no shore power.

Comment: It is important to have a very low resistance path between battery negative terminal and inverter negative terminal. If it is possible to bond them both to the chassis very securely, and verify that the resulting resistance is very low, then you can do that. To be safe, you should probably run a heavy gauge cable between them. That way you can be sure the resistance is low. You still need to have a good connection to chassis ground because, as others have said, the chassis is probably being used for ground return currents in your system. I would make that connection near the battery.

Comment: As far as AC grounding goes, this is really a tricky subject, and I am disappointing in the installation manual because it pretty much bypasses it. Are you going to use the outlet on the inverter, or are you going to have an AC circuit breaker panel and AC wiring inside the vehicle?

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee you that if you put a 40A fuse between the battery and the inverter, there will be no way to get 2000 W out of the inverter. Not even for 10 seconds. You probably won't even get 1000 W for 10 seconds. Either the inverter will trip or the fuse will blow.

Comment: @mkeith, thank you for your replies and sorry it's taken me so long to reply, but i'm back! (A) you're absolutely right that between the battery and the inverter needs something more than a 40A fuse. I calculate now that I need 2000W/12v=166.6666667A for circuit breaker. So I will find the next lowest circuit breaker below that value.

Comment: @mkeith (B) It would be nice if I could do AC wiring inside the vehicle - it already has household outlets that were connected to shore power before. But there is an outlet on the inverter that I can use if it's too difficult.

Comment: @mkeith (C) I think I should ground the battery to the chassis and connect the inverter to the battery. All the cable I'm using is 2/0 gauge, if I calculated correctly it should be overkill for everything. I'm going to solder car battery eyelet terminals onto the cable, then use wire brush to scrub the chassis metal and bolt it on there. Do you think that sounds more right?

Comment: Actually solder is not a good way to do battery cables. Ideally they should be crimped, but crimp tools can be expensive for heavy cable. There are some hammer crimp tools that are not too expensive. I am not sure if they are reliable, but I used one once for a battery cable. How long is the wire run between inverter and battery? 10 feet of 2/0 cable has around 0.078 mOhms. 200 Amps * 0.078 mOhms = 0.15 V. So I would say that if the wires are short, 2/0 is OK. If the wire run is longer than 15 feet or so, you might consider going to 4/0.

Comment: I would suggest a 200 A fuse, assuming the wire insulation temperature is over 100C.

Comment: I think the chassis GND should make use of a metal stud permanently attached to the chassis, and a ring terminal crimped onto the cable. A nut would secure the ring terminal on the chassis stud.

Comment: I thought I need a safety lower than the calculated value, not higher? Does it matter if I use a fuse or a circuit breaker?

Comment: Fuse or circuit breaker is OK. Rating should be higher than normal useage to avoid having the fuse or breaker trip when there is no fault condition. Fuse or breaker rating should be matched to wire diameter and insulation temperature. You can find an "ampacity table" online. But the ampacity tables are usually for homes, and they are based on insulation temperature rating. If you use high temperature automotive wire, you can allow a bit more current.

Comment: If using a fuse of circuit breaker make sure it is rated for DC use.  If you never draw the full rating from the inverter then you can down rate your input (and output) fuses a bit.

Comment: There are a couple of questions on SE about the resistance, reasons and viability of using a car chassis as ground.  I would read them as well. The consensus if I recall was that the sheer size of the ground makes it viable and cheaper than multiple copper wires.

Answer (score 2):

You should always follow the wiring recommendations supplied by the inverter manufacturer.  Absent those recommendations, I would proceed as follows:

Treat the battery as your "Star" point.

The cables from both the positive and negative leads of the inverter should go directly to the battery.  These need to be thick and as short as possible.  Also be sure to include adequate over-current protection in the inverter Positive lead.

The leads from your charging source(s) should also terminate at the battery.  Again: include adequate over-current protection.

If you require a system Earth ground, that also connects directly to the battery Negative terminal.

Under no circumstances should you attempt to use the metal chassis as a current-carrying conductor.

Note that when I say "Battery Terminal", this is often a buss-bar arrangement with many connection points.  These are located very near to the battery bank.

Common buss-bar tie points that I use derive from the Telcom industry and are 3/8" thick copper bars about 3" wide by as long as necessary with numerous 1/4-20 and/or 5/16-18 tapped holes.

Finally, note that many inexpensive consumer-grade AC inverters will NOT allow the Neutral output conductor to be grounded.  That is because the internal DC-DC converter is not isolated from the output stage.  In these inexpensive inverters, the Line & Neutral terminals alternate in polarity between the DC ground line and the high-voltage positive output of the internal DC-DC converter.

Attempting to ground the Neutral output conductor results in either blown fuses or blown output switching devices.

Comment: "Under no circumstances should you attempt to use the metal chassis as a current-carrying conductor."  This is an odd statement as every other standard component on a car does just that.  Granted the current demanded here is high it is not as high as the starter motor current which usually also uses the chassis.

Comment: @KalleMP We talk about PV setup and inverter. This topic is very different from a regular car installation. If you have separate wire to send current instead of using chassis will save you a lot of trouble in the future, some charge controllers and inverters devices simply don't have the isolated lines.

Answer (score 1):

The grounds for the DC circuits will be best using a good connection to the chassis with short cables. Note that I said for the DC circuit, as that seems to be what you are asking about. I do not have the knowledge level to comfortably tell you where or how to ground anything on the AC side of the system.

Answer (score 0):

2000W from 12V equates to 167A.  Depending on the design of your inverter, if the supply voltage drops a little, the input current may increase yet further.  There will inevitably be some voltage drop in the wiring but you should aim to keep it as small as possible.  Using the chassis as a return path may be acceptable provided that you keep the resistance as low as possible - use copper or brass screws in preference to steel, and avoid stainless steel.  Use star washers and ensure that the contact area to the chassis is large and clean.  You can measure the voltage drop on both the positive and negative sides to see whether the performance is satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

In your manual on page 12, step # 8) it addresses the earth ground. It also says "marine and automotive may not apply". That's because there is no earth ground in a vehicle. I have that same inverter in my camper van and did not connect the earth ground. It has been working perfectly for over a year now. As far as using the vehicle chassis for 12V ground, it "can" be less reliable. I used thick #00 pure copper welding cable with hydraulically crimped ring terminals for both 12V Positive and Negative connections - fairly short at only 3' long (with a 250Amp fuse)... No problems running a 15 Amp water kettle.